# My prefix cools you down, My suffix is way up high

Tags: riddle, rhyme, affix-riddle

> My prefix cools you down.
>
> My suffix is way up high.
>
> My infix is a single noun.
>
> My whole is gold, no lies.

Hint (added more and more):

> *(digital)*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is

> FANATIC

My prefix cools you down.

> a FAN can cool you down

My suffix is way up high.

> an ATTIC is the highest room in a house

My infix is a single noun.

> TI is a single noun indicating a musical note

My whole is gold, no lies.

> FANATIC is a digital gold award/badge (as opposed to the bronze or silver badges) given by the well known site puzzling.stackexchange for visiting the site on 100 successive days (with out resting; lie is a synonym for rest); so therefore... *no lies*!
>  This also matches the hint.

Answer (score 3):

Let me have another crack at this bad boy:

> Stonefly

because

> 1) Stone is notoriously cold to the touch and has a cooling effect hence the popular dictum stone-cold

> 2) Fly, when objects or animals fly, they are often found to be high up above

> 3) One is a noun and single is a rather apt description of it

> 4) Stoneflies can be yellowish/gold in colour

Comment: The clue makes me think of one very specific word, but I thought you guessed it and were told it was incorrect before it was deleted rot13(zrqnyyvba). Can you confirm @Deepthinker101

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is

> Honest

My prefix cools you down.

> H, or Hydrogen is very cold in liquid form, and is used to freeze things.

My suffix is way up high.

> NEST is often up in a tree or another high place.

My infix is a single noun.

> ONE, a single number and can be used a noun

My whole is gold, no lies.

> If you have gold, it is important to get an honest appraisal or someone might try to cheat you out of it. Also an honest person tells no lies.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not right, but close enough to try.

My prefix cools you down.

> N - Nitrogen ('N' on the periodic table); [liquid nitrogen is very cold](https://askdruniverse.wsu.edu/2015/12/26/why-is-liquid-nitrogen-so-cold/)

My suffix is way up high.

> He - Helium ('He' on the periodic table); helium gas is light and [when filling a balloon propels it high into the air](https://science.howstuffworks.com/helium2.htm)

My infix is a single noun.

> Ich - this is a stretch, but it *is* a word for a [tropical fish disease](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/ich)

My whole is gold, no lies.

> Niche - also a stretch, but one definition is "[an ornamental recess in a wall or the like, usually semicircular in plan and arched, as for a statue or other decorative object.](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/niche)", so a gold trophy or medal could fill a niche in someone's wall.

Answer (score 1):

It may be

> solid

because:

My prefix cools you down.

> SO, or significant other, can cool you down metaphorically if you're angry/upset

My suffix is way up high.

> lid, it's always the highest point of the object

My infix is a single noun.

> oli - [The Oli](https://www.kamehamehafestival.org/exhibitions-parent/ho-okuku-oli-chant-competition/) (Hawaiian Chant) falls into two broad categories, *mele oli* and mele hula. Mele oli are chants delivered with no musical instruments and *are generally performed by one individual*. Regardless, *the* chant itself is a singular noun.

My whole is gold, no lies.

> solid, if there's no lies then it's solid gold, rather than plated or hollow

Answer (score 0):

I wish it were this, though I don't see how all of the pieces fit perfectly:

> Cryptocurrency

My prefix cools you down:

> Often crypts are underground and have a cool temperature.

My suffix is way up high:

> Depending on where you are your currency could be worth a lot I suppose?

My infix is a single noun:

> Cur is a noun (insult).

My whole is gold, no lies:

> One of the main ideas in cryptocurrency is a distributed ledger which prevents lies.  It's also like digital "gold" as hinted.

Answer (score 0):

Giving this a shot:

> Halcyon

> My prefix cools you down.

> [Hal cold oral](https://www.google.com/search?q=hal+cold+oral&sxsrf=ALeKk00eQK_0Y5PfmUaxZogYVvKfmecCug%3A1625993867641&ei=i7LqYM7GJsjG-QaaqaPQCQ&oq=hal+cold+oral&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQghEKABMgUIIRCgAToLCAAQsAMQBxAKEB46CQgAELADEAgQHjoLCAAQsAMQCBAKEB46CAgAEBYQChAeSgQIQRgBUJvkAVjK7QFg8_IBaAFwAHgAgAFqiAG_BJIBAzQuMpgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQrAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz&ved=0ahUKEwiOuIyX09rxAhVIY94KHZrUCJoQ4dUDCA4&uact=5)

> My suffix is way up high.

> On meaning "I put the food on the clouds"

> My infix is a single noun.

> Cy can be short for cyan, cyanide etc.

> My whole is gold, no lies.

> Halcyon's synonyms have "golden" in it, and halcyon's meaning is calm and peaceful.